# sed - replacing line with special characters

Tags: bash, sed

not quite sure how to get this working. apologies, i'm kinda new to this.

so i have a file with a line that starts with

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ
```

I want to repace that line with

```
</head>
```

I can't seem to get it going. I understand I need something like this:

```
sed 's/^    <script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ/hello/g index3.html
```

but I am not sure where to escape the special characters. obviously the '/' needs it. can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 2):

Use alternate regex delimiter, other than `/` since your matching text has `/` in it:

```
sed -i.bak 's~^ *<script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ~</head>~' index3.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape just about anything using backslash:

```
sed "s/^    <script type=\"text\/javascript\">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ/hello/g" index3.html
```

The nice thing about `sed` is that you can also use alternate delimeters. It will use whatever you put after the `s`, which means you wouldn't have to escape a slash:

```
sed "s#^    <script type=\"text/javascript\">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ#hello#g" index3.html
```

Answer (score 1):

you can escape them by backslash; but you can also write

```
sed 's!...!...!'
```

(the '!' can be an arbitrary character)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sed 's|<script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ|</head>|'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "/<script type=\"text\/javascript\">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ/ s#.*#</head>#"
```

You can also keep the space at the begining with  `s#^\( *\).*#\1</head>#"`